# Saving webpage content into variables

Tags: powershell

I am sure my brain is shrinking by the minute...

What I am doing is retrieving a webpage, getting some information and emailing that information, all from powershell. The emailing part is working fine but I am having a few issues with the webpage processing part.
My initial idea was to get the page, download it to a temp file, do the processing then delete the file. Then I remeber doing a similar script in TCL about 12 year ago and my approach was to pass the page content to variable then call the variable to process the data using regexp.

```
$storageDir = "C:\Users\me\Documents"
$browser=new-object system.net.webclient
$browser.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$browser.downloadfile("http://whatever.com/cgi-bin/search_detail.cgi?num=01","$storageDir\Download1.HTML")
```

The above will save my file for processing but like I said, I think is better and cleaner to pass to a variable, not sure how to do that in powershell.

I am searching for the following 3 tags. All these fields will end up in &nbsp, I dont need that in the return.
These are the fields and the format of the fields I am interested in passing the string to a variable:

This field will be alphanumeric

```
CAL_ID:</font><td>tt1234 &nbsp;
```

This field will be letters

```
CAL_FIRST:</font><td>TILAHUN &nbsp;
```

This field will be a phone number and the format can vary, it should be as shown but it can be input without any phone separators or the usual () for the area code, spaces and such.

```
CAL_NE:</font><td>123-456-7890 &nbsp;
```

Normally in TCL i would have done something like this after calling the http package:

```
set posting [::http::geturl http://whateever.com/searchonly -query query]
set raw_data [::http::data $posting]
```

then use the contents of the page in $raw_data to get my variables, something like:

```
set data [regexp -all -inline -- {CAL_ID:</font><td>([^\>]*) &nbsp;} $raw_data]
```

and so on for each other field I need.

My head is just not working and getting frustrated. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Need to start with a little forward. So you think that downloading the html to file is inefficient? In this case it might be since you are doing some data extraction first. Why not just use `$browser.DownloadString` instead then?

```
$html = $browser.DownloadString(....)
```

OK so we have our html in the variable `$html` and we need to extract data that comes in lines. For the purpose of testing this is the content I used for `$html`.

```
This field will be alphanumeric
CAL_ID:</font><td>tt1234 &nbsp;
This field will be letters
Thivll be letters
s field wiCAL_FIRST:</font><td>TILAHUN &nbsp;
This field will be a phone number and the format can vary, it should be as shown but it can be input without any phone separators or the usual () for the area code, spaces and such.
s field wiCAL_NE:</font><td>123-456-7890 &nbsp;
```

Following is the code that extracts the data.

```
$html | select-string -Pattern 'CAL_(ID|FIRST|NE).*?&nbsp;' -AllMatches | 
        ForEach-Object{$_.Matches} |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value |
        ForEach-Object{
            $_ -replace [regex]::escape("</font><td>") -replace " &nbsp;" -replace ":","=" | ConvertFrom-StringData
}
```

Sample Output

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                                                                        
CAL_ID                         tt1234                                                                                                                                       
CAL_FIRST                      TILAHUN                                                                                                                                      
CAL_NE                         123-456-7890
```

Using `Select-String` we located all the data that starts with "CAL_" and one of the following ID, FIRST or NE. Grab everything up until the next occurrence of " ". Then we take that data which would look something like this ( based on aforementioned sample.)

```
CAL_ID:</font><td>tt1234 &nbsp;
CAL_FIRST:</font><td>TILAHUN &nbsp;
CAL_ID:</font><td>tt1234 &nbsp;
CAL_FIRST:</font><td>TILAHUN &nbsp;
CAL_NE:</font><td>123-456-7890 &nbsp;
```

Trimming the fat we remove "", the trailing "  " and convert colon to a equal sign. The last part with the equal sign is just so that we can use `ConvertFrom-StringData` which takes string input in the form of "key=value" so that we can output a nice object.

**Self Criticism**

I opted to use `select-string` as I thought it might be easier to swallow but I feel that a simple regex with PowerShell named captures might be better.

__Update From Comments_

You mentioned that you wanted the data in a variable in both the title and comment. The part you neglected to mention is that you wanted it in *variables*. Technically you just need to save the output as a variable and the data you are looking for is saved as parameters. So the above code would have this for the first line instead

```
$result = $html | select-string -Pattern 'CAL_(ID|FIRST|NE).*?&nbsp;' -AllMatches |
```

Then you could access the data like so since it is an array.

```
$result.CAL_NE
```

*Note:* This works best if you only have those entries appearing once in the data. Originally I had them appear multiple times to be able to account for that.

If you *really* want the results in variables that is where `New-Variable` comes into play.

```
$html | select-string -Pattern 'CAL_(ID|FIRST|NE).*?&nbsp;' -AllMatches | 
        ForEach-Object{$_.Matches} |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value |
        ForEach-Object{
            $text = $_ -replace [regex]::escape("</font><td>") -replace " &nbsp;"
            New-Variable -Name $text.split(":")[0] -Value $text.split(":")[1]
}
```

The you could access `$CAL_ID`

```
PS C:\users\Cameron\Downloads> $CAL_ID
tt1234
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It of course works but I am having difficulty assigning the value to a variable. The variable can be set up as the Name. I looked into convertfrom-stringdata, it does have a -OutVariable parameter but at this time im unsure if that will work for what I want, assign each Value to a variable. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: right now I am doing:
    $test = $_ -replace "CAL_(ID|FIRST|NE)" -replace [regex]::escape("</font><td>") -replace " &nbsp;" -replace ":"
Of course, test gets assigned each value and the final result is the last value on the last interaction which I uderstand. I could probably use a $i++ loop type to change names but I thought it would be more elegant if the variable takes the Name itself, meaning 
$CAL_ID=tt1234
$CAL_FIRST=TILAHUN     
$CAL_NE=123-456-7890

Comment: Matt, thanks for your help. One more time I dont say what I mean and mean what I dont say... It is funny, I was using the new-variable in my script using the $i $i++ loop and did not thought to just use the name as you used it. The answer was right on my face, geez! Thanks one more time.